# Javascript - Global variable not being updated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update a global variable within a callback function (see code below)

```
function FunctionOne() {
    var result = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         AjaxFunction(function (data) {
            result += data;
         });
    }

    alert(result);
}

function AjaxFunction(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/test',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```

When I alert `result` it always seems to be blank. Can you guys please tell me whats wrong?

Comment: No `SyntaxError` because of the missing `)`? Or is that a typo.

Comment: You're alerting the value before the ajax is finished. move alert iside your callback function.

Comment: @TomHart No, don't - it'll break up the async program flow

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this question has subtleties not addressed in the canonical answer, such as how to make the eventual result depend on _all ten_ AJAX calls...

Answer (score 3):

Result is not global, it is only defined within the scope of `FunctionOne()`. However in your example you are alerting the value, before it has been assigned as the Ajax call appears to run asynchronously. Instead try alerting after you update your value.

```
function FunctionOne() {
var result = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     AjaxFunction(function (data) {
        result += data;
        alert(result); // this should have the value
     }
}

alert(result); // this should be empty
}
```

Comment: you can just move the var statement out of the function so it will become global

Comment: That is also only part of the problem - the callback to increment will happen *after* the value has been alerted.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Yup, was editing my answer as you were typing you're comment. Updated now.

Comment: `result` is still accessible to the passed function through it's **closure**.

Comment: @Ian how do i get the correct value to appear on the second alert?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to your question that need to be resolved - the first relates to the asynchronous nature of AJAX and how results are returned - for that see [the canonical answer to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) that this was originally marked as a duplicate of.

The second part is how to make the final answer depend on the asynchronous completion of *all ten* AJAX requests:

```
function functionOne() {
    // initiate ten requests, storing the promises in an array
    var def = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        def[i] = AjaxFunction();
    }

    // wait for all the promises to complete, with the
    // eventual result also being returned as a promise
    return $.when.apply($, def).then(function() {
        // take a copy of the arguments
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);   

        // concatenate them all together
        return args.reduce(function(prev, current) {
            return prev + current[0];   // each arg is actually a 3-element array
        }, "");
    });
}

function AjaxFunction() {
    return $.get('/test');  // NB: using promises - no callback required
};

// NB: functionOne() is now also async - you have to wait
//     for the promise to be resolved before using the result

functionOne().then(function(result) {
    alert(result);
)};
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/5s28G/ for a working demo.

Comment: which version of jQuery includes Promises?

Comment: @COBOL Anything from 1.5 onwards.  The usage of `.then()` above is from 1.8 onwards (ISTR)

Comment: The project I'm working on is a legacy project and is using 1.4, so I will have to solve this problem without promises

Comment: @COBOL that's a shame - they really are the best way to solve this.  FWIW, there are third party Promises libraries that you could potentially add to jQuery 1.4 that would give very similar functionality (`Q`, perhaps - https://github.com/kriskowal/q ?)